# Long traitement in a onMessage() : How to handle ? I want this method to be called by a thread

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, jms, activemq-classic

I do some heavy traitement at  reception of  JMS message, with  high risk of timeout.

whole point of using JMS for me is to allow this kind of computation to be done asynchronisely. ( I dont want my other consumer to block if one of them block, i dont want my producer to block, ever ). **ideally, i also want my consumer to be able to receive  second message during  computation of  first one**

Right now, i'm using  unique [javax.jms.Session](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/jms/Session.html%20javax.jms.Session)  for sending, and consuming my message. 
I'm aware it was  conception mistake. As  doc state :

> session can create and service multiple message producers and consumers.

But also :

> If  client desires to have one thread produce messages while others consume them,  client should use  separate session for its producing thread.

solution could be to use  session for  producer, and  different session for each consumer, but  consumers will still be able to handle only one message at  time

**For my understanding  onMessage method is called by  Jms Provider ( ActiveMq in my case ). Could any configuration allow this call to be call in several thread ?**

Maybe this question is  reflect of  major flaw in my understanding of how JMS should be use / my conception. Please fell free to discuss ;)

Thanks !

Edit :

my problem in one sentence :

- if i have 2 consumer, and if one of them take  long time to process onMessge, all  other consumer will blocK.

**What is done today :** I'm using a [java.util.concurent.Executor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html), but i'm not a big fan of this solution. I'm in a Tomcat application server context, and already using too much thread, i will like to delegate this responsability to a more robust bunch of code. ( Eg : activeMq )

Edit 2 :

More detail :

- I dont use transactional session
- I use  Auto_Acknoledge

Answer (score 1):

Your description is a hard to follow, and I *don't* think it's a language issue. My best understanding is that your producer is blocking because the consumer takes a long time to process the message. If true, this implies that you're using durable messages and explicit acknowledgment after processing the message.

And if that's the case, the two possible solutions are: (1) decide whether you really need the guarantees and use implicit acknowledgment and/or non-durable messages if not, or (2) reliably store the message in the consumer, acknowledge, and then process the message.

---

Based on your edits, the short answer is "yes, you can spawn threads." Since the producer doesn't care whether the consumer is able to actually process the message, you have a lot of flexibility in how you handle it.

I suspect that ActiveMQ has some property that would allow you to control the number of message-processing threads. I haven't used it extensively (prefer HornetQ), so can't give a definitive answer.

However, even if it does, I'd prefer using a Java `ThreadPoolExecutorService` (I think that's the name of it; see `java.util.concurrent`).  The main reason is that it provides its own internal work queue. No matter how many threads you give to the messaging framework, there's always the possibility that you'll have enough work to tie them up. With the `ExecutorService`, you will continue to receive and queue messages until you run out of memory (and if that happens, you have some design issues to resolve).

Comment: Hi, a rogue chrome plugin has deleted all the "a" and "the" in my post. Fun bugs. :) I have edited my question, i hope it's more clear now

Comment: @Antoine - the edits provided useful information, particularly edit #2. Answer updated accordingly.

Comment: thanks for your edit. Actually, i'm already using a Executor on the consumer side to handle timeout and long process time. But i'm not really confortable with this solution, for my understanding, it should be the JMS providers responsability. I will look for a "numberOfMessageProcessingThread" config value in activeMq.

Answer (score 1):

[javax.jms.Session](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/jms/Session.html) and below (MessageConsumer, MessageProducer) are single-threaded.  If you want any multithreading, you want multiple Sessions.  One Session per consumer.

Each consumer will be single-threaded.  But a JMS implementation should be able to multi-thread message deliver between multiple consumers if they're created from multiple sessions.

Comment: Indeed. Multiple session looks a thing to do. But what if i have a unique single threaded consumer, with several session. ( one session by JMS subscription )

Answer (score 0):

You should simply cut down your heavy traitement into a process that can be handled into one transaction.

I can not help you since you don't mention what this traitement is about.